# one or the other in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, logical-operators

first we have this:

```
def some(a):
    if a is None or "*":
         print "*"
    else:
         print a

>>> some("*")
    *
>>> some("d")
    *
```

it failed but I couldn't give myself a good enough reason why it failed.
Apparently it is because I wrote it wrong, a working version would be:

```
def some(a):
    if a in [None, "*"]: # or write [ if a is None or a is "*" ]
         print "*"
    else:
         print a


   >>> some("*")
       *
   >>> some("d")
       d
```

Although it's almost intuitive enough to just write the correct version but I couldn't explain to myself why the first version failed.

so the question is, why the first version failed?

Comment: Also note, the "working" version should be `a in [None, "*"]`. As you've written it, `(None or "*")` is evaluated as a boolean expression, which will return the first `True`-equivalent component, which is `"*"`. Then your code will test `a is "*"`. Try `some(None)` to see what I mean.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp thanks for the note, I did miss that part, it should be in a square bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement:

```
if a is None or "*":
```

Semantically means

```
if ((a is None) is True) or (the value "*" is True)
```

And the value `"*"`, being a non empty string is always `True`.  Thus, the whole expression will evaluate to `True`.

Comment: aha! moment, thanks a lot. Indeed, this makes good sense.

Answer (score 1):

This will always evaluate as True

```
 if a is None or "*":
```

You could have said this if you wanted

```
 if a is None or a== "*":
```

Answer (score 1):

The following statement doesn't do what you're expecting:

```
if a is None or "*":
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if (a is None) or "*":
```

so it's always `True`.  To get the behavior you want, use:

```
if a is None or a == "*":
```